# How to set up fineuploader to sync?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, fine-uploader, uploader

When I set it to async: false .
But it is not synchronized.
How to set up fineuploader to sync?
Please help me.

```
<script>
    $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger').fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
        request: {
            endpoint: '/server/uploads'
        },
        callbacks: {
            onAllComplete : function (succeeded, failed) {
            }
        },
        autoUpload: false,
        multiple: true,
        async: false,
        disableCancelForFormUploads: false
    });

    $('#trigger-upload').click(function() {
        $('#fine-uploader-manual-trigger').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There is no such option, and there never will be. Synchronous AJAX requests are dangerous and unnecessary.